# gcc compiler error: "cannot find -lcs50 collect2: Id returned 1 exit status"

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cygwin, cs50

I have a problem in 'c' language inside compiling with gcc.

1. I am using "Cygwin" with (gcc-core, gcc-g++, gdb, make & other supportive packages) inside windows xp.
2. I installed "Cygwin" on this path "C:\Cygwin\".
3. My home directory: "C:\Cygwin\home\Bhanu Pratap"
4. I copied "cs50.h" and "cs50.c" inside my working directory which is also under "C:\Cygwin\home\Bhanu Pratap".

This is code inside my hello.c file

```
#include "cs50.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void){
  string name = "David";
  printf("O hai, %s!\n", name);
}
```

This is command under bash (Cygwin)

```
gcc -o hello hello.c -lc50
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/id: cannot find -lcs50
collect2: Id returned 1 exit status
```

Please help me where i am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use `-lcs50`, you'll first need to build that library (`cs50`) from its source code (`cs50.c`).

Alternatively, you could simply:

```
gcc -o hello hello.c cs50.c
```

assuming `cs50.c` doesn't have other dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using the cs50 library file, and I've noticed in the code that you've used is :

```
#include "cs50.h"
#include <stdio.h>
```

and also this command :

```
gcc -o hello hello.c -lc50
```

just wondered why you used quotation marks, instead of '< >'
and the last part of the command `-lc50`

we normally use it this way:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

and  `-lcs50`

hope this helps \m/

Answer (score 1):

I am using DJGPP (gcc) compiler in Windows XP for CS50 edX course.

I have tried different solutions from answers, but none of them helped me (though [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat) gave me a clue).

Here is a solution:

1) copy `cs50.h` and `cs50.c` from *[`library50-c-5.zip`](https://manual.cs50.net/library/#windows)* into a directory, where your .c source file, which you want to compile, is located.

2) type into your .c source file: `#include "cs50.h"`

3) compile your .c source file (at cmd.exe prompt, for example): `gcc custom.c -o custom cs50.c`

You may copy `cmd.exe` from "*`C:\WINDOWS\system32*" folder into your working folder (with your .c files). In this case you don't have to change directory for navigating to your working files, when you start up command prompt window.

Comment: An alternate method of opening up command prompt in the directory you want is to shift+rightclick on the folder you want it to open in (make sure it isn't over a file) and select `Open command window here`.  It's easier than copying `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Alas! it doesn't work on my Windows XP system. Though, I will try it on another Windows (7) machine.

Answer (score 0):

See the link http://manual.cs50.net for relevant guidance about guidance about installing the cs50.h library.  They have a precompiled version of the cs50 library that can be downloaded and installed.  It is worth a try.  They used gcc to compile the library, and they beginning to switch over to clang, which can also produce 64 bit compatible libraries, which is going to more useful in the future.